# How to migrate pandas code to pandas arrow?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-arrow

Recently pandas 2.0 supported arrow datatypes, which seem to have many advantages over the standard datatypes, both in speed and with nan support.

I need to migrate a large code base to pandas arrow and I was wondering which kind of problems I may face, I didn´t find any migration guide or similar.

I imagine I will need to change all the functions that load data so they use the arrow back-end. Now integer columns will support NA, that is not a big deal, but my questions are:

- I'm missing something, possible issues or incompatibilities?
- Are common data-types interoperable?
- Is such a migration feasible?
- which other problems may I face?

I hope these questions are not to broad for SO.

Answer (score 2):

There is a short [PyArrow user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html) in the official pandas documentation.

Instantiation can be done using aliases for dtypes:

```
ser = pd.Series([-1.5, 0.2, None], dtype='float32[pyarrow]')

0    -1.5
1     0.2
2    <NA>
dtype: float[pyarrow]
```

Or specifying the engine:

```
data = io.StringIO('''a,b,c
   1,2.5,True
   3,4.5,False
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, engine='pyarrow')
```

Operations are compatible between PyArrow and classical pandas objects:

```
ser.add(pd.Series([1, 2, 3]))

0    -0.5
1     2.2
2    <NA>
dtype: float[pyarrow]
```

One major difference with classical pandas object might be the support of nested structures (which would result in the object dtype, like Series of lists, with numpy-based pandas):

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

pa_array = pa.array(
    [{'1': '2'}, {'10': '20'}, None],
    type=pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string()),
)

ser = pd.Series(pd.arrays.ArrowExtensionArray(pa_array))

0      [('1', '2')]
1    [('10', '20')]
2              <NA>
dtype: map<string, string>[pyarrow]
```

Expected advantages will be the improved performance on some operations (a [few examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html#operations) are given in the documentation):

> PyArrow data structure integration is implemented through pandas’
> ExtensionArray interface; therefore, supported functionality exists
> where this interface is integrated within the pandas API.
> Additionally, this functionality is accelerated with PyArrow compute
> functions where available.
>
> This includes:
>
> - Numeric aggregations
> - Numeric arithmetic
> - Numeric rounding
> - Logical and comparison functions
> - String functionality
> - Datetime functionality

Comment: Thanks for your answer! very useful specially to know the compatibility, but does this mean that there is no or almost no risk / incompatibilities for changing the back-end? I can simply swap the load and everything will work?

Comment: It's probably to soon to tell now. When the nullable dtypes were introduced several bugs were found. Give it a try, report bugs and everything should be fine in the long term ;)

Answer (score 2):

## For large codes I encountered major adjustment to be necessary to migrate from pandas 1.x.x to pandas 2.x.x.

There were a bunch of quite subtle changes in the pandas interface (compare [Backwards incompatible API changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-api-changes)) like this one:

> Creating a new DataFrame using a full slice on both axes with loc or
> iloc (thus, df.loc[:, :] or df.iloc[:, :]) now returns a new DataFrame
> (shallow copy) instead of the original DataFrame, consistent with
> other methods to get a full slice (for example df.loc[:] or df[:])
> (GH49469)

Chances are pretty high, that existing unittests will not capture (all of those) changes and upgrading pandas will introduce bugs, like a variable referring now to a shallow copy of a `DataFrame` (pandas 2.x.x) as compared to the `DataFrame` directly (pandas 1.x.x).

### As of August 2023, there are no migration guides or open source tools available addressing this topic.

I would recommend to automatically run the code/unittests with a debugger in parallel on pandas 1.x.x and pandas 2.x.x and compare the local variables.

[image: Scheme to migrate code from pandas 1 to pandas 2]

This concept is taken from here ([Migrate code from pandas 1 to pandas 2](https://www.algorithmus-schmiede.de/migrate-code-from-pandas-1-to-pandas-2/)), where you can also find a more detailed discussion of the topic.